# Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken is returning a null value

Tags: apex, oauth

I have an `Auth. Provider` setup through `Microsoft Access Control Service` that was created using [this tutorial](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_provider_microsoft.htm&language=en_US#register_application).

Whenever I try and call `Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken('0xxx0000000000x','Microsoft Access Control Service')`, it returns a null value. I have cleared my cache just in case due to [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100579/getaccesstoken-is-returning-null-when-using-microsoft-access-control-source) but that unfortunately did not work for me.

Does anyone have some insight into what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I got the Answer from here: Stackoverflow ([Custom REST controller to access Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken returning null](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321814/custom-rest-controller-to-access-auth-authtoken-getaccesstoken-returning-null))

Simple Answer is: Open Authentication Provider, open on the OAuth-Only Initialization URL, login. Now you get the Accesstoken!