# Custom REST controller to access Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken returning null

Tags: apex, apexrest, oauth, namedcredentials, auth-provider

Following on from a previous question:

- [How to access OAuth Token stored in NamedCredential using Apex for use in other third party application](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321677/how-to-access-oauth-token-stored-in-namedcredential-using-apex-for-use-in-other)

I've created a custom REST endpoint which proxies access to `Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken(authProviderId, providerName);` as suggested by @identigral.

**Apex REST controller class using API v49.0**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/AccessToken/*')
global with sharing class AccessTokenRESTController {
    @HttpGet
    global static void getAccessToken() {
        try {
            String token = Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken(authProviderId, providerName);

            System.debug(token);

            if (token == null) {
                RestContext.response.statusCode = 404;
                RestContext.Response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('Unable to find token for authProviderId: ' + authProviderId);
                //return; // commented out for debugging
            }

            AccessTokenInfo info = new AccessTokenInfo();
            info.AuthProviderId = authProviderId;
            info.AccessToken = token;

            RestContext.Response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            RestContext.Response.statusCode = 200;
            RestContext.Response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serializePretty(info));
        } catch (Exception error) {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, error);
            throw error;
        }
    }

    public class AccessTokenInfo {
        public String Name {
            get {
                return UserInfo.getName();
            }
        }
        public String Username {
            get {
                return UserInfo.getUsername();
            }
        }
        public String AccessToken { get; set; }
        public String AuthProviderId { get; set; }
    }

    private static String authProviderId {
        get {
            List<AuthProvider> providers = [SELECT Id FROM AuthProvider WHERE DeveloperName = :authProviderDeveloperName];

            if (providers.size() == 0) {
                throw new CustomException('Unable to find an Auth. Provider with DeveloperName: ' + authProviderDeveloperName);
            }

            System.debug(providers);

            return providers[0].Id;
        }
    }

    private static String authProviderDeveloperName {
        get {
            return 'MockLab';
        }
    }

    private static String providerName {
        get {
            return 'Open ID Connect';
        }
    }
}
```

The REST controller is accessible via a `Site` and I am passing a bearer token when I call the endpoint.

The `Auth. Provider` configuration is:

- Provider Type: `Open ID Connect`
- Name: `MockLab`
- URL Suffix: `MockLab`
- Consumer Key: `mocklab_oauth2`
- Consumer Secret: `whatever`
- Authorize Endpoint URL: `http://weyz3.mocklab.io/oauth/authorize`
- Token Endpoint URL: `http://weyz3.mocklab.io/oauth/token`
- User Info Endpoint URL: blank
- Token Issuer: blank
- Default Scopes: blank
- Send access token in header: `true`
- Send client credentials in header: false
- Include Consumer Secret in API Responses: `true`
- Custom Error URL: blank
- Custom Logout URL: blank
- Registration Handler: blank
- Execute Registration As: blank
- Portal: blank
- Icon URL: blank

The `NamedCredential` configuration is:

- Label: `MockLab`
- Name: `MockLab`
- URL: `https://weyz3.mocklab.io/`
- Certificate: blank
- Identity Type: `Named Principal`
- Authentication Protocol: `OAuth 2.0`
- Authentication Provider: `MockLab`
- Scope: `openid, profile, email`
- Authentication Status: `Authenticated`
- Generate Authorization Header: `true`
- Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Header: false
- Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Body: false
- Outbound Network Connection: false

I've completed the `OAuth` flow, so the `NamedCredential` has an `Authentication Status` of `Authenticated`.

I've also tested the `NamedCredential` works by connecting to the external API and fetching some data using Apex.

But when I call my custom REST endpoint to get the access token, I always get a `null` value.

Example response:

```
{
  "Username" : "xxx@xxx.com",
  "Name" : "Admin User",
  "AuthProviderId" : "0SO4K000000GozdWAC",
  "AccessToken" : null
}
```

Based on the response, I can see the request has successfully authenticated using the bearer token.

But the call to `Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken(authProviderId, providerName);` is still returning `null`

If I try running this code in the developer console:

```
String token = Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken('0SO4K000000GozdWAC', 'Open ID Connect');
System.debug(token);
```

I get a `null` value.

I've tried calling the method via a LWC component:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static String getAccessToken() {
    return Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken('0SO4K000000GozdWAC', 'Open ID Connect');
}
```

I get a `null` value.

Everything is done using the same Admin user.

UPDATE: I've changed the `Auth. Provider` and `Named Credenital` details to the actual values for a `MockLab` environment I have set up, so you can test using exactly the same information/setup I am using.

**Questions**

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I fix it, so the controller returns the token?

Comment: You completed the OAuth flow as the NamedCredential as some user. Are you using the same user to authorize the call to the REST web service?

Comment: @identigral - I believe so. I completed the OAuth flow as Salesforce Admin, and I'm accessing the site page using a bearer token for the same Salesforce Admin. The external system I completed the OAuth flow against uses the same email address as the salesforce admin user. What details should I be checking are the same to ensure this is correct?

Comment: @Robs Got some update from SF developer support : they said R&D team is aware of a "potential" issue to get the token. The issue is not considered a bug at the moment, so no Known Issue can be created since the issue is technically still considered under investigation

Comment: @Shamina Do you happen to know if SF lists these kind of issues under investigation anywhere? Or is it know only within their internal team?

Comment: @arut as per SF support, its only internal for now and scheduled build is planned for Spring 21. they provided 2 internal investigation numbers W-8080901, W-7845636 as reference for followup in the future

Comment: Thanks @Shamina for the quick response.

Comment: Thanks @Shamina - I really appreciate you raising a case with your premium support, it has made all the difference. I mentioned the internal investigation number in my case, and they have confirmed everything and said there is a fix due for release in Feb 2021.

Thanks again :-)

Comment: @Robs :) No worries, I'm happy to help. Hope you find a workaround in the meantime the issue is fixed

Comment: @Robs @Shamina I guess both of you might have already noticed the updated answer by Adam. But since there were too many comments going on, just wanted to explicitly mention here. Visiting `Auth-Only Initialization URL` manually once actually seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

**Edited**

I did some tests with your code and setup in a Developer Org,

[image]

---

Test 1: Log in as the user who created the Auth. Provider in Workbench

Result: I can get the token in workbench.

[image]

---

Test 2: Grant apex class access to a site and visit the site

Result: I got a `null` as a site user.

[image]

---

Test 3: Log in as another System Admin in Workbench

Result: I got a `null`

[image]

---

I guess only the user created the `Auth. Provider` can get the token using `Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken(authProviderId, providerName);`

Can you confirm that the username in your sample response is the same as the username of the Salesforce Admin that created the Auth.Provider?

---

I [created a Connected App](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/build-a-connected-app-for-api-integration/create-a-connected-app#) and got a token of the current user

[image]

then I used the user token to call the rest api and managed to get the AccessToken in Postman.

[image]

While it is possible to successfully get the token, this introduces a new token.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for offering your assistance. Interesting idea to call the Apex REST endpoint from the workbench! I had not thought of that. As suggested, I've called my endpoint from workbench as the same user who created the `Auth. Provider` and created and authorised the `NamedCredential` but I still get a `null` AccessToken value.

Comment: Hi Adam, I've updated the question with actual details for a `OAuth2` mock endpoint I am testing against.

Comment: @Robs In your previous question, what kind of authorization is used to get Salesforce tokens in ESB?

Comment: please could you be a little more specific? The ESB is connected to Salesforce via a connected app?

Comment: I can get the `AccessToken` in the workbench, so the solution using `Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken` in the REST API is possible. 

But I got a `null` as another System Admin, so I think only the user created the Auth. Provider can get the token.

I then created a connected app to call the REST API on behalf of the user who created the Auth. Provider, and it works.

Since this connected app solution introduces a new token, I'd like to ask how you connect ESB to Salesforce, because if you're already using the connected app, this may not be an issue.

Comment: That's really strange, because it never works for me!? and I am always using the same Admin user.

Comment: @Robs If not done, log a case with SF support in parallel, this could be a bug not yet reported. and just wondering, which API version is running the code `Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken` ? @Adam can you also share the API version used when running the code in Workbench?

Comment: @Shamina - I've raised a case, but I got told they wouldn't help because I don't have a Developer Support license

Comment: @Shamina both API versions are 49

Comment: I am using API 49

Comment: @Adam, Can you provide some details related to your first screenshot (*workbench screenshot showing the access token value*)? Like what were the configuration values used for the Auth provider and the connected app? Did you use mocklab indicated in Rob's question for this or did you use OpenIDConnect mentioned in your answer update?

Comment: @arut I updated my answer,  I use the same code and settings as Rob.

Comment: @Adam I had used exactly the same settings shown in your updated answer (or the one in Rob's question) and I used sys admin user for creating Auth Provider as well as login to workbench. But, I still get `null` for the access token. I suspect there could is some other org setting or user setting that is responsible for this behavior. Did you try this on a different DEV org?

Comment: @arut Have you visited the "OAuth-Only Initialization URL"  listed In the Auth. Provider page?

Comment: @Adam I missed out to perform this step while on a new org this morning. In my earlier attempts on my usual dev org, I didn't explicitly visit this URL but had attempted to authenticate via Named Credential. Both, visiting this URL and authenticating via Named Credential takes me to the same login page for mocklab (where I can enter any email/ password) **i.e., the same oauth flow**. I wonder why the auth via Named Credential didn't have any impact in my previous attempts. Regardless, explicitly visiting the `OAuth-Only Initialization URL` fixed the problem. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I guess visiting the "Test-Only Initialization URL" would have the same effect (because this takes me thru the same auth flow), although I didn't test this out yet on a different org.